# PostgreSQL query in two tables with CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table `publications` and `publication_likes`, where I have a many to many relationship and this fields: `user_id`, `pub_id`, `created_at`.

Users have a profile and on that profile they have publications.
I need to get a specific user's publications, when his profile is requested(that's easy). Also I need to know which of those publications the user who is logged in likes.

Example: `user_a` is the profile owner and has publications, `user_b` is logged in and visits `user_a` profile. Server loads `user_a` publications and tells `user_b` which of those `user_a` publications has liked

Before asking I tried thinking and found a solution, but I don't know if it is correct

```
 SELECT p.id, 
      p.user_id as creator, 
      p.p_content, 
      CASE WHEN pl.user_id = $1 THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
       END as liked from publications p
  LEFT JOIN publications_likes pl on p.id = pl.pub_id 
  WHERE p.user_id = $2;
```

Please tell me if you think this is right or not and if there is another way to do the same.

NOTE: I know the title it is not really specific but I could not think of other. If you can make it better, feel free to do it.

Comment: I'm confused by `which of that publications the user who is logged in likes.` Do you mean `user_a` is logged in & looking at the profile of `user_b`, and you need to fetch all the publications liked by `user_b` to show to `user_a` or publications by `user_b` that `user_a` has liked.

Comment: yes, I have `user_a` who has some publications, and `user_b` who may have liked `user_a` publications and is logged in. I need to get `user_a` publications and at the same time to know which from that publications `user_b` likes. :-)

Comment: your statement is giving you the correct result, although you could simplify the case statement as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51354276/2570261). just ensure that `$1` = `user who is viewing profile and liked publications` & `$2` = `user who created publication`

Comment: Yeah, I already simplified it. Do you consider this is a good and optimized way to do it? do you have any recommendation? :-)

Comment: yes, this is a good way to write this query.  IMO the suggested answer should be accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Updated to reflect clarification in comments.

You can get the correct result set without needing to use a `CASE` statement.

```
 SELECT p.id, 
       p.user_id as creator, 
       p.p_content, 
       pl.id IS NOT NULL AS liked 
   FROM publications p
   LEFT JOIN publications_likes pl ON p.id = pl.pub_id AND pl.user_id = $1
   WHERE p.user_id = $2;
```

You'll need to use two conditions on the join to ensure you're finding the correct `pl` row, since you're joining to a junction table for a M:N relationship. Otherwise you don't really know which `pl` you'll actually join to, and you may end up with false-negatives for `liked`.

Comment: Thanks, The user who likes the publications is not the profile owner. I have the owner of the profile: `user_a`. There is a `user_b` who likes `user_a` publications. I need to get publications of `user_a` and then or at the same time to know which of those `user_a` publications is liked by `user_b`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, edited my answer to reflect this.